# Date reversed when saving Excel workbook with macro

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a CSV file with a column of dates in US format (my regional formatting is UK).
If I open the CSV file in excel and then save the file manually it modifies the date entries slightly (if recognised as valid UK dates) but saves them in the same format.
However, if I save the workbook with a macro using **ActiveWorkbook.Save** the dates are reversed (the ones that are recognised as valid UK dates that is).

What the heck is going on?
How do I save with a macro and avoid this?

Example input file:

```
Date
06/02/2020
06/30/2020
07/13/2020
07/22/2020
07/31/2020
08/11/2020
08/11/2020
08/31/2020
09/22/2020
09/29/2020
```

After manually saving:

```
Date
6/02/2020
06/30/2020
07/13/2020
07/22/2020
07/31/2020
8/11/2020
8/11/2020
08/31/2020
09/22/2020
09/29/2020
```

After saving with macro:

```
Date
2/6/2020
06/30/2020
07/13/2020
07/22/2020
07/31/2020
11/8/2020
11/8/2020
08/31/2020
09/22/2020
09/29/2020
```

**Solution:**
The solution as pointed out in Ron's answer was to replace the Save line with SaveAs setting the Local variable to True so it didn't use the VBA US region default.

```
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.FullName, Local:=True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem stems from **open**ing the csv file in your version of Excel.

When you **open** the file, Excel assumes any dates will have the same short-date format as your Windows Regional Settings.

Since your WRS is `DMY` and the csv file dates are `MDY`

- Dates where the 2nd part is <=12 will be interpreted incorrectly as `DMY`
- Dates where the 2nd part is >12 will be retained as text

To prevent this from happening, **before** the CSV file gets into Excel (gets written to an Excel worksheet), you **must** tell Excel the format of the incoming dates.

One method (and the best in my opinion) is to **import** the CSV file, using either the legacy wizard or Power Query. When you do that you will be afforded an opportunity to tell Excel the format of the incoming data.

A workaround is to create the CSV with unambiguous dates.  `yyyy-mm-dd` usually works, as might `dd-mmm-yy` although the latter will have problems with language differences where month abbreviations are different.

To have the dates saved in the same format, you could

- import the dates, then format that column, in Excel, as `mm/dd/yyy` before saving it again.
- import the dates but, during the import process, designate that column as `text`. This will only work if that column will not be modified, or used for any computations, while the workbook is open.

**EDIT**

Another possibility, which might help in your ***specific*** example, might be to set the `Local` parameter of the `Workbook.SaveAs` method to `True`, so the file is saved in the language/settings of Excel, rather than VBA. Although doing so might work in this instance, it is far from bulletproof and might cause problems down the road depending on what the end user wants to do with these dates. *I am guessing that when SaveAs is executed from the Excel worksheet, it will save using the language/settings of Excel (I have not seen documentation for this); whereas VBA being US-centric, it is saving in the language of VBA (ie: USA) unless Local is specified.*

Comment: Botton line - Excels attempt to "helpfully" recognise dates is often not only not helpfull, but also destructive.  IMHO your workaround (unambiguous dates) is the best and correct solution, when you have control of the source.  If you don't have controll of the source, I usually resort to writing my own CSV handler, when I have a-priori knowledge of the actual format

Comment: @chrisneilsen I agree. Although these days I'm more likely to "write my handler" by setting up a query using Power Query.

Comment: I don't think you quite get what I'm asking, what I mean is why does a manual save and a VBA save behave completely differently? What I'm actually doing is opening an existing CSV file, adding a column and saving it via a macro. When the macro saves the file it reverses the dates however if I leave out the save function from the macro and save the file manually then it doesn't reverse the dates. I want to be able to do that within the macro without it messing the dates up.

Comment: To clarify, there is no problem with how it opens the file. I'm perfectly happy with it recognising some of the dates as UK format when I open the file. If I manually save them it saves the dates it recognises as UK format which is fine as it matches how it read them. The problem is that the save function in the macro, saves the dates as US format instead of UK format so it reverses them to how it opened them.

Comment: @GodKratos The dates you think it is recognizing are not being recognized as they were originally intended.

Comment: I know that, but that's not the problem I need to solve.

Comment: @GodKratos Take a look at my edit. I am guessing that when `SaveAs` is executed from the worksheet, it saves in the local language; but when executed from VBA (where Local defaults to False if not specified), it will save in the language of VBA which is US english

Comment: Terrific thanks, that was what I needed!  The solution was to replace ActiveWorkbook.Save with ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.FullName, Local:=True